# How to use @ConfigurationProperties on an abstract class field with fully configured subclases/classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can't understand how to use @ConfigurationProperties on this case in the correct way.
I have an abstract configuration class, where i want to use configuration properties named JobProperties:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@PropertySource("classpath:job-configurations.properties")
public abstract class BaseJobConfig {
   @Autowired
   private JobRepository jobRepository; 

   // some other autowired beans      

   private JobProperties jobProperties;
   // getJobProperties() and setJobProperties(JobProperties jobProperties)

   @Bean
   public CommonBean commonBean() {...}

   // some other beans definitions
...
```

Next, i have two concrete classes:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("migration-job")
public class MigrationJobConfig extends BaseJobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Service1 service1;

    @Bean
    public CommonBean migrationBean() {...}

    // some other beans definitions
...
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("cleanup-job")
public class CleanupJobConfig extends BaseJobConfig {
       @Autowired
       private Service2 service2;

       @Bean
       public CommonBean cleanupBean() {...}

       // some other beans definitions
...
```

This is the property file `job-configurations.properties`:

```
cleanup-job.job-properties.data-source-schema=schema1
migration-job.job-properties.data-source-schema=schema2
```

This type of configs works correctly, but the IDE (IntelliJ) don't recognize `data-source-schema` nested property, but only the parent `job-properties`, so my my doubts are :

**Is this type of configuration semantically correct?** From what I've seen Spring says to use @ConfigurationProperties only on standard POJO, but here I have the annotation on @Configuration classes with definitions of @Bean and @Autowired of other beans. So I wanted to understand if I should "move away" the @ConfigurationProperties annotation and if so how can I replicate this configuration property inheritance behavior based on subclass properties. Any other ideas also to have the correct autocompilation of nested properties by the IDE in this kind of situation?

Thanks to all of you in advance

Comment: Are you running the VERY latest IntelliJ? They recently fixed several bugs re this issue that I filed and they STILL have bugs with it. If Spring loads them properly, I wouldn't lose sleep over the IDE. You can work around it with `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`

Comment: Yes, i run the latest. I read something about these issues in their forums and I "temporarily" solved it using the @NestedConfigurationProperty annotation but I honestly don't understand why it shouldn't work without it. Do you think it could be a problem related to what I asked in the question?

Comment: if Spring is loading them as you say, then its an IntelliJ bug. I've reported 3-4 bugs with properties not being recognized. They've fixed a couple of them, but I still need to use `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` for some other cases.